# install gcc-4.4 on ubuntu 15.01 in ns2

Tags: ns2

i need to install sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4 in ubuntu 15.01

this error 
mona@mona-Inspiron-5537:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc-4.4
[sudo] password for mona: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package gcc-4.4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gcc-4.4' has no installation candidate
mona@mona-Inspiron-5537:~$

Answer (score 0):

---

The last Ubuntu version with g++-4.4/gcc-4.4 was Ubuntu 14.04 .

? ns-2.35 ? You don't have to use the old year 2011 version ( ns-allinone-2.35.tar.gz ).
There are updated versions, e.g. ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSGJCZ2YzUGJDVk0/view?usp=sharing

"ns-allinone-2.35_gcc482.tar.gz" will build with the later gcc´s : Versions 4.6 ... 5.2 .

---

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Knud Larsen for this answer!This worked for me.So I am Sharing it

Getting g++-4.4 / gcc-4.4 : gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

Then add two new lines to the file :

deb [URL] trusty main universe
deb [URL] trusty-updates main universe
My example :

deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main universe
deb http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main universe
Run sudo apt-get update, and you can install gcc-4.4 : sudo apt-get install g++-4.4

Answer (score 0):

You can try this command, with gcc version 4.8: `sudo apt-get install gcc-4.8`